# Background image not displaying in proxy browsers (opera mini and UC browser)

Tags: html, css, django

I have the following in django project

```css
.home {
  height: 100vh;
  /*background-image: url('../../media/background_for_homepage.jpg');*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  -webkit-background-size: contain;
     -moz-background-size: contain;
       -o-background-size: contain;
          background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="home" style="background-image: url('../..{{background.image.url}}');">
  </div>
```

It works well on major browsers and CM Browser(a proxy browser) but not on Opera mini and UC Browser.

Please I would like to know what workaround is available to display the background image on such browsers. Thank you

PS: the image is dynamically generated

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Answer (score 0):

try `min-height:100%` or fix `height`

```
.home {
  min-height: 100%;
  /*background-image: url('../../media/background_for_homepage.jpg');*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  -webkit-background-size: contain;
     -moz-background-size: contain;
       -o-background-size: contain;
          background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: I have a containing div with height set to 100vh as well, when I change that to 100%, the background doesn't display on any browser

Comment: add html - height- 100%; & body min-height:100%;

Comment: Thanks a lot. I inserted a transparent image into the div. That did the trick